# Printing the minimum value out of a list (PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.x

new to python just trying to figure out how to print the minimum of this generated list, but its giving me the error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

and this is my code,

```
number = []
for number in range(1,21)
print min(number)
```

I have tried several things including

```
print(min(int(number)))
```

Which seems like since its giving me an int problem would solve it, no?

Comment: Try `min(range(1,21))` to get the minimum of that list. `min` doesn't work on single ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for number in range(x, y)` every `number` in that range represents a single `int` you cannot take the `min` of a single `int`. However you could append all those values to your empty list `number` and then take the `min` of that `list`, but even so we could just print the `min` of the *entire* `range(x, y)`

```
number = []
for i in range(1,21):
    number.append(i)
print(min(number)) # => 1
```

Or just using the `range` itself:

```
print(min(range(1, 12))) # => 1
```

Comment: Awesome thats what I was thinking, thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @RobertLewis No prob! Keep learning and comeback soon :)